# Issue with CNAME and Virtual Hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, virtualhost, cname-record

I'm using Apache and I have a CNAME DNS record for

> sub2.sub1.domain1.com that points to sub1.domain1.com

And I have an A DNS record for

> sub1.domain1.com that points to the IP.

Then in my httpd.conf file I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.domain1.com
        DocumentRoot /domain1/www
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sub1.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /domain1/sub1/www
</VirtualHost>
```

Yet I appear to be missing something, as when you visit sub2.sub1.domain1.com, it shows you the page for domain1.com. When you visit the sub1.domain1.com, it shows the correct page for sub1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though you have CNAME record to point sub2.sub1.domain1.com to the correct server, apache server maybe serving multiple website.

When a http request come in, apache check the URL against *ServerName* to determine which website to serve out. Should there be any additional name pointing to the same website, you put them in *ServerAlias*.

In your httpd.conf, you have to add *ServerAlias* for sub2.sub1.domain1.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub1.domain.com
    ServerAlias sub2.sub1.domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /domain1/sub1/www
</VirtualHost>
```

Additionally, the first *VirtualHost* declaration in httpd.conf is used as the *default*. When a http request comes in and doesn't match any *ServerName* and *ServerAlias*, the *default* site is serve out.

Comment: I was under the impression that when utilizing a CNAME record though, I wouldn't have to change any settings in apache.

Comment: Updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: So will I be able to add 10,000 server alias's then? Google Apps lets you create CNAMES. For example mail.domain1.com that all point to ghs.googlehosted.com; Essentially I'm going to be offering a service that will need to allow clients to setup CNAMEs and I will need to handle those requests.

Comment: So then, I dont need to do utilize ServerAlias, and just use the default VirtualHost declaration.

Comment: @mrc0der If they are going to the same website, you add them to *ServerAlias* of the corresponding *VirtualHost* section. If they are seperate website, you create new *VirtualHost* section for each of them.

Comment: Even for CNAMEs. CNAMEs don't change the URL you send to the webserver, that would break encapsulation in all sorts of ways if your browser acted like that.